# Can cygnus be used to trigger a change in Context Broker?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I am developing a service agent where I want to know when the values of sensor are changed. Instead of developing an automatic http request in my service to query context broker (each 15 mins or so) I want to know if I can configure cygnus to notify me of these changes?

Im doing this because I want to put the data coming from my sensors in an algorithm that detects certain trends.

Thank you, I hope my question is clear enough.

**If you are not an experienced user of fiware technologies please ignore this question.**

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is better that you subscribe and end point (integrated with your service) to orion so your service is notified when the sensor value change.

https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Context_subscriptions

Do you really need to use Cygnus?

Comment: No I dont need to use Cygnus, I just thought it would help me achieve what I want.

Comment: Have you achieved it?

Comment: As commented, if you simply need to know when an attribute changes, then it is better your application directly receives the notification and compare the new value with the old one (which can be stored in memory). Nevertheless, if your trending analysis requires several last values for certain time window (and this could be big), then you will need to store those values somewhere special, and in that case Cygnus must be used (it can persists historical data in HDFS, MySQL, MongoDB, STH, CKAN and in next release, in Kafka queues).